# how to make View dinamically in Fragment

Tags: android, view, fragment

I want to dynamically make View such as TextView or ImageView in Fragment because I don't no how many Views I do need until get data from the Internet.

How can I dynamically make View in Fragment?

sorry, I'm not native English Speaker and I'm beginner of Android.

structure is follow

MyActivity
--MyFragment
　--ImageView  (I want to make dynamically)
　--TextView   (I want to make dynamically)

Could you please teach me this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Views in code by calling their constructor. E.g.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Hello World");
```

You then have to add this newly created view to a main layout.

Here is a [Guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Android_User_Interface_in_Java_Code)

Comment: I lerned that I should create or get a Layout in onCreateView method in Fragment class, and call addView method, then return the Layout.
Thank you.

Comment: That is correct. And if you want to add views to the layout later, you can save the layout in a private field.